# AngularJS: Editing a form values not coming in scope

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-forms

I am using a form to create an user in my application. I am also using the same form to update the user profile and I am loading the values from database. if user does not change anything in the edit form and submit the form, the scope does not have the user data. for example.

```
<select ng-model="user.gender">
    <option ng-selected="userGender==male" value="male">male</optoin>
    <option ng-selected="userGender==female" value="female">female</option>
</select>
```

submit function:

```
$scope.updateUser = function() {
        var userData = $scope.user;
        var url = '/userModule';

        $http.post(url, userData).
        success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
```

if user will not touch the gender dropdown, while submitting the form will not have the gender index in the user scope object.

How can I get all the ng-pristine or ng-untouched fields into the scope.

Comment: show your JavaScript code pls

Comment: @shushanthp, I am using angularJS, in controller I am trying to send the user scope object.

Comment: We won't be able to understand what's going on without the JS code.

Comment: not sure exactly what you are asking ,if it is related to select box ,then Simon H answer will work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using camelCase for userGender, but isn't this what you need?

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('myctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.user.gender = 'female';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myctrl">
  <select ng-model="user.gender">
    <option ng-selected="user.gender=='male'" value="male">male</option>
    <option ng-selected="user.gender=='female'" value="female">female</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: userGender is a scope property, it will hold the user gender value, while loading the edit template, i am comparing the options with the userGender property and it will set the option accordingly, Now if i will click on submit button user scope object will not be there.